# Selenium example code does not work, what is the wrong?

Tags: python, selenium

I am new to python and learning selenium now. but when I download the selenium and try the example code provided by selenium it does not work at all.

the code is here

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://www.python.org")
assert "Python" in driver.title
elem = driver.find_element_by_name("q")
elem.clear()
elem.send_keys("pycon")
elem.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
assert "No results found." not in driver.page_source
driver.close()
```

the message from python is :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<tmp 1>", line 4, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Ie()
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\ie\webdriver.py", line 49, in __init__
    self.iedriver.start()
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 71, in start
    os.path.basename(self.path), self.start_error_message)
WebDriverException: Message: 'IEDriverServer.exe' executable needs to be in PATH. Please download from http://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/index.html and read up at https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/InternetExplorerDriver
```

I do not quite understand the problem. Help please.

Comment: I installed the selenium by pip

Comment: I realize this may be due to selenium can't find firefox. but I do not know how to point the path to selenium.

Answer (score 2):

1) Download any driver to emulate the browser. Your message says you need to download IEDriverServer from:

http://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=3.0/

If you have 32-bits windows, download "IEDriverServer_Win32_3.0.0.zip", otherwise try the x64 version below.

2) Unzip the file and place anywhere. I placed for example in C:\libraryIE  (i created a folder).

3) in your code change the first line

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox('C:\libraryIE\IEDriverServer.exe')
```